# TightVNC viewer doesn't show anything when I click/type

Tags: networking, windows-xp, wifi, vnc, ubuntu-9.04

We have a wireless network where I work.

I've installed TightVNC viewer on a WinXP box, and I'm using it to connect to my laptop which has Ubuntu 9.04 installed.

So far, everything works right up to after I login.

I can see the initial screen of my laptop in the TightVNC viewer, as it is when I first connect.

But if I click on something, enter keystrokes, etc, none of my actions seem to show up.

The actions still happen, as observed on the laptop's screen, but I don't get any output on my WinXP box.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you using Remote Desktop (vino) on your Ubuntu Box? I'm using that and TightVNC viewer from Vista and having a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a number of options in the TightVNC server, including one ('-viewonly') that disallows keyboard and mouse input from the viewer. On your Ubuntu box, do you have a ~/.vnc/xstartup file defined? Which options are you starting your TightVNC server with?

Comment: He may be using Remote Desktop (vino) which is installed by default, IIRC, on Ubuntu. I'm using the same combination (vino with TightVNC **viewer**) and am having the same problem. Also, the screen doesn't update (e.g. the clock doesn't change). However, when screen blanking kicks in, it does so on the viewer also and I can move the remote mouse and it wakes up and the clock shows the current time (but again stays unchanged). I have "View only (inputs ignored)" turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the message [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/share-your-ubuntu-desktop-using-remote-desktop.html/comment-page-2#comment-9220):

> On the remote machine (the one you are
>   remoting to);
>   System->Preferences->Appearance
>   “Visual effects” tab, select None.

Which refers to a Gnome setting on the Ubuntu system. Unfortunately, this turns off Compiz effects like wiggly windows.

Comment: I had tried RealVNC Viewer Free in addition to TightVNC Viewer and got the same results which led me to checking for problems on the host side.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did: killed all vino processes and tightvncserver.  Then restarted tightvncserver (without args).  Connected to the box (running ubuntu) from an xp box and got what you'd expect--just like you were on the Ubuntu box, only slower.

Answer (score 0):

There are different option for pulling the display ( well basically pull or using events) try changing them. Pulling will be more reliable, but it uses more cpu cycles.

Answer (score 0):

When you press `Ctrl` or `Alt` key while in the tightvnc viewer, the click and typing doesn't work. You can resume this by pressing the `Ctrl` and `Alt` key again while the window of vnc viewer is active. You can see the `Ctrl` and `Alt` icons being enabled/disabled in the viewer by pressing those keys.

Sometimes when you switch to different windows using `Alt+Tab` keys, the `Alt` key is enabled in vnc viewer and when you come back to the vnc viewer you will not be able to click and type. Simply press the `Alt` key again and voila you will be able to click and type again.

If there is some way to disable this functionality that would be really appreciated.